# Perl - Hash of Hash - test if entry exists

Tags: perl, hash, hash-of-hashes

I have a problem, when I try to find if a entry exists in my Hash of Hash and if it don't exists, Perl create me this entry. 
Exemple of my code :

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash;

$hash{'key1'}{'subkey1'} = "value1";

if ( defined($hash{'key2'}{'subkey2'}) ) {
    print "Here\n";
}

print keys %hash;
```

This code return :

```
key1key2
```

What is the best way to catch if this entry exists AND DONT add this in the Hash ?
I have try with "exists" "defined" and it's a same thing.

Thank's for your support.
And sorry for my English.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must first test for `key2` before you can test for `subkey2`

```
if (defined($hash{'key2'}) && defined($hash{'key2'}{'subkey2'}) ) {
    print "Here\n";
}
```

Otherwise, Perl creates `$hash{'key2'}` in order to check for `subkey2`.

Comment: Or just drop in the [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/autovivification/lib/autovivification.pm) module and include the `no autovivification;` pragma.